# Ruby - Control child threads from main thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, queue

The main program is creating a child thread. The child thread is running a loop and this thread needs to be paused and resumed based on events taking place in main thread.

What would the best way to accomplish this? IPC?

Comment: How about a [Fiber](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fiber.html)?

Comment: `mythread.stop` and `mythread.run` http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html

Answer (score 0):

Communication between thread should be done using thread safe classes.

You can use Queue since it as a blocking method: pop.

If you want a more specific response you need to provide more details about your use case.